# How to find the hex code from a percentage of color?

Tags: css, colors

For instance, how do I find hex code of 30% black? Is it equivalent to `#4d4d4d`?

Comment: 30% black? What does that mean?

Comment: If I knew, I wouldn't be asking.

Comment: You mean 30% opacity/transparency?

Comment: I usually get these requests from designers that I work with. They usually say "make that color 30% black" and things like that.

Comment: I don't know why this was down voted.  The answer is that 30% black refers to CMYK and not RGB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your designer is giving you colors in CMYK, which is often used in print.

CMYK stands for Cyan Magenta Yellow Key (Black), and works on percentages

To answer your specific question, 30% black is #b3b3b3

You can use this tool to find more (or do it in Photoshop using color picker)

http://www.ginifab.com/feeds/pms/cmyk_to_rgb.php